# Is "make it different" a good sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

I want to create a tagline for my clothing brand. As the title says, the tagline is:

> Make it different

I want the tagline to describe to consumers that:

- These products are exclusive, and
- The consumer will feel different while using my products.

Does "**make it different**" sound good?

Comment: I think only a special context can make it sound good, for example: _Does your outfit seem too usual? Make it different!_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to stick as closely to your proposed slogan as possible, I would suggest altering it slightly to

> Makes a difference

This links nicely to your second bullet point in that it is clear that wearing it will have a positive effect on the consumer.

Your current phrasing is more like a command to someone else that they should make 'it' different from other items.

An alternative phrasing just occurred to me as well. You could say,

> [Brand name]. Made differently.

That would also get your point across.

Comment: I think "makes a difference" fit for my brand. Thanks!

Comment: Is that tagline fit for this sentence?
Good style start with exclusive outfit. Let "makes a difference".

Comment: It should either be "Good style start with this exclusive outfit. Let's make a difference." or "Good style start with this exclusive outfit. It makes a difference."